# How can I avoid creating multiple use-case-specific adapter classes for my business logic classes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Many of the .net framework objects, especially UI widgets, like to take their operands as generic objects and then use reflection to look for component-specific attributes that describe how they should be used. But I don't want to pollute my business logic objects with a bunch of display-related attributes, nor do I want the arrangement of properties to be dictated by the tastes of some external component. My impulse for dealing with this has been to create adapter classes. For example, suppose I have this object:

```
public class BusinessLogicObject
{
   public int Prop1 { get; set; }
   public int Prop2 { get; set; }
   public int Prop3 { get; set; }

   void Operation1() { /* ... */ }
   void Operation2() { /* ... */ }
}
```

To use it with `PropertyGrid`, I might do this:

```
public class BLOPropertyGridAdapter
{
   private readonly BusinessLogicObject _blo;

   public BLOPropertyGridAdapter(BusinessLogicObject blo)
   {
      _blo = blo;
   }

   [Category("BLO Properties")]
   [Description("This is property 1")]
   [DisplayName("Property 1")]
   public int Prop1
   {
      get { return _blo.Prop1; }
      set { _blo.Prop1 = value; }
   }

   [Category("BLO Properties")]
   [Description("This is property 2")]
   [DisplayName("Property 2")]
   public int Prop2
   {
      get { return _blo.Prop2; }
      set { _blo.Prop2 = value; }
   }

   // don't want Prop3 to be visible in the grid, so omitted
}
```

But then I decide I want XML serialization too (I know there are other ways to achieve this and that the code is contrived anyway; bear with me for the sake of the example):

```
public class BLOXmlAdapter
{
   [XmlElement("Property1")]
   public int Prop1 { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("Property2")]
   public int Prop2 { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("Property3")]
   public int Prop3 { get; set; }

   // yuk!
   public void ApplyToBLO(BusinessLogicObject blo)
   {
      blo.Prop1 = Prop1;
      blo.Prop2 = Prop2;
      blo.Prop3 = Prop3;
   }

   // yuk!
   public void PopulateFromBLO(BusinessLogicObject blo)
   {
      Prop1 = blo.Prop1;
      Prop2 = blo.Prop2;
      Prop3 = blo.Prop3;
   }
```

}

Now maybe I decide I want to save a `BusinessLogicObject` in the application's `Settings` file, so I have to do it all again. Aside from all the extra work I had to do, I've created a maintainability nightmare. Surely there is a better way?!

One thing I might try is to combine all the adapters into a "properties" class loaded with tons of attributes and then compose the business logic object with an instance of that class:

```
public class BusinessLogicObject
{
   private BLOProperties _properties;

   public BusinessLogicObject(BLOProperties properties)
   {
      _properties = properties;
   }

   public void Operation1() { /* ... */ }
   public void Operation2() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Followed consistently, this would lead to a codebase consisting of dumb data objects and collections of functions for operating on them. In other words, C.

What is the proper idiomatic way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when it comes to this type of thing it's *recommended* you go with this type of approach because it allows you to decouple your BL from your consumers.

I think you would need to be more specific on what exactly you deem a "*maintainability nightmare*". It seems perfectly natural to have an adapter per consumer because each consumer will more than likely have different requirements.

Comment: What I mean is, if I add a `Prop4` to BLO, I need to remember to update *n* different adapters. And if I forget one, it will be a silent failure. It could be weeks before I get a report saying "the new Prop4 is really cool, but it doesn't seem to persist between sessions." And oops; I remembered to add it to all the adapters including the XML serializer, but I forgot to add a line to `ApplyToBLO()` so the value was being serialized in and promptly discarded.

Comment: @dlf This is why you use Unit Tests. :)

Comment: @dif it has pros & cons, in the scenario where you want to apply *global* changes to all adapters it means having to update every one. However, it also gives you the flexibility of updating one without affecting the others. alstonp also makes a good point, these are things that good unit tests would catch. Are all your adapters just going to decorate the properties with attributes? Or is there more too them?

Comment: @alstonp Good point; the unit test is one more thing I'd have to update! :) More seriously, if I forgot to add the feature, I presumably forgot to add a test for the feature too.

Comment: @James re: are they all just decorators. Most of the time, but sometimes I will flatten hierarchy, impose min/max limits or the like as well.